# How does the name of an immutable object rebind to the result of an augmented assignment?

Tags: python, binding, namespaces, variable-assignment

How does the name of an immutable object rebind to the result of an augmented assignment?

For mutable objects, example, if `x = [1, 2, 3]`, and y = [4, 5], then when we do x += y, it is executed as `x.__iadd__(y)` which modifies `x` *in place* and does the name `x` rebind to it again?

And how does it work when `x` is immutable? Here's what Python documentation has to say about augmented assignments.

> If x is an instance of a class that does not define a `__iadd__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`.

OK, now if `x = (1, 2, 3)` and `y = (4, 5)` when we do `x += y`, python executes `x.__add__(y)` which creates a **new** object. **But when and how does this new object get *rebound* to `x`?**

I went spelunking in the source code of CPython specifically the `tuple` object ([tupleobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/de85a9c7fe94/Objects/tupleobject.c)) and `AugAssign` parts in [Python-ast.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/de85a9c7fe94/Python/Python-ast.c) and [ast.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/de85a9c7fe94/Python/ast.c), but couldn't really understand how the rebinding occurs.

**EDIT**: Removed the misconceptions in the original question and changed them to question form to prevent confusing future readers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A line like

```
x += y
```

is actually translated to the equivalent of

```
x = x.__iadd__(y)
```

The rebinding always happens, even if `x` is mutable.  If `__iadd__()` is implemented in a way that performs an in-place operation, it needs to return `self`, and the name is rebound to the object it pointed to anyway.  If `__iadd__()` is not implemented, the usual addition methods `__add__()` or `__radd__()` are used instead, as you already noted in your post.

This is why `x += y` inside a function renders `x` a local name.  (Explanation: In Python, a name is considered local to a function if there is an assignment to this name inside the function.  `x += y` is considered an assignment to `x`, so `x` is considered local to a function containing such a line.  See this [blog post by Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) for more information.)

Another example of this behaviour:

```
t = ([], 1)
t[0] += [1]
```

results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

but the list is appended anyway.  This is because first `list.__iadd__()` is called, changing the list in place.  Next, `t[0] = <list object>` is attempted, resulting in the error.

Detailed documentation on the semantics can be found in the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) and in [PEP 203](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/).  A quote from the former:

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target. The target is only evaluated once.
>
> An augmented assignment expression like x += 1 can be rewritten as x = x + 1 to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the augmented version, x is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead.

Comment: Good example, you can also see it in the bytecode. Do `def x(y): y += y; import dis; dis.dis(x)` - it does INPLACE_ADD then STORE_FAST.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 2 questions though. If I examine tuple using `dir()` tuple doesn't show an `__iadd__()` method. Doesn't this mean internally `__add__()` is being used? Good to know that rebinding occurs even for mutable objects. Can you please elaborate on "This is why x += y inside a function renders x a local variable." I am not quite sure I understand what you mean by that statement.

Comment: @PraveenGollakota: Added further details to my answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks a lot for the clarification. I did not know about the PEP for AugAssign. I need to start looking up for PEP's before I start looking at the source code. :)

Comment: @JochenRitzel Thanks for the bytecode example with `dis`. I knew the module existed but wasn't really familiar with its workings. Now I went over PyMOTW and standard library details about the module. Definitely very useful to understand what's going on *under the hood*.

Answer (score 2):

The augmented assignments - `+=` `*=` and so on are actually assignments, that do bind the left hand names to the return result of the corresponding operator.

So, if you have a class that offers "`__iadd__`", and perform  `obj += expr`  on an object of that class, the method `obj.__iadd__(expr)` is called and its return value is assigned to the name "obj".

Example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def __iadd__(self, other):
...       return "fixed value"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a += ["anything"]
>>> print a
fixed value
```

BTW, if the object's class don't define the enhanced operators, the regular version is called by Pythonś machinery