# Strange behavior with a list as a default function argument

Tags: python, list, default-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [List extending strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904039/list-extending-strange-behaviour)
>   [Pyramid traversal view lookup using method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076046/pyramid-traversal-view-lookup-using-method-names)

Let's say I have this function:

```
def a(b=[]):
    b += [1]
    print b
```

Calling it yields this result:

```
>>> a()
[1]
>>> a()
[1, 1]
>>> a()
[1, 1, 1]
```

When I change `b += [1]` to `b = b + [1]`, the behavior of the function changes:

```
>>> a()
[1]
>>> a()
[1]
>>> a()
[1]
```

How does `b = b + [1]` differ from `b += [1]`? Why does this happen?

Comment: You're re-binding `b` during the scope of the function... using `b+=` doesn't do that...

Comment: And `list += sequence` is not the same as `list = list + list`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python there is no guarantee that `a += b` does the same thing as `a = a + b`.

For lists, `someList += otherList` modifies `someList` in place, basically equivalent to `someList.extend(otherList)`, and then rebinds the name `someList` to that same list.  `someList = someList + otherList`, on the other hand, constructs a *new* list by concatenating the two lists, and binds the name `someList` to that new list.

This means that, with `+=`, the name winds up pointing to the same object it already was pointing to, while with `+`, it points to a new object.  Since function defaults are only evaluated once (see [this much-cited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)), this means that with `+=` the operations pile up because they all modify the same original object (the default argument).

Comment: > and then rebinds the name `someList` to that same list. < I don't think this is true. It doesn't rebind, just changes the list calling its `extend` method.

Comment: @warwaruk: It is true.  You can see it if the assignment is to an attribute (e.g., make an object whose `__setattr__` prints something out, do `obj.someProp=[1]`, then do `obj.someProp += [2]` and watch `__setattr__` get called).  See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943613/how-does-the-name-of-an-immutable-object-rebind-to-the-result-of-an-augmented-as).

Comment: Indeed, `+=` and `+` for lists are two separate implementations: [List extending strange behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904039/13904124#13904124)

Comment: Hm, you are right. I could not understand why, until i figured out, that `obj.a_list += another_list` is equivalent to `obj.a_list = operator.iadd(obj.a_list, another_list)` and not `obj.a_list.extend(another_list)`

Answer (score 5):

`b += [1]` alters the function default (leading to the least astonishment FAQ). `b = b + [1]` takes the default argument `b` - creates a new list with the `+ [1]`, and binds that to `b`. One mutates the list - the other creates a new one.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function

```
>>> def a(b=[]):
    b += [1]
    return b
```

it saves all the default arguments in a special place. It can be actually accessed by:

```
>>> a.func_defaults
([],)
```

The first default value is a `list` has the ID:

```
>>> id(a.func_defaults[0])
15182184
```

Let's try to invoke the function:

```
>>> print a()
[1]
>>> print a()
[1, 1]
```

and see the ID of the value returned:

```
>>> print id(a())
15182184
>>> print id(a())
15182184
```

As you may see, it's the same as the ID of the list of the first default value.

The different output of the function is explained by the fact that `b+=...` modifies the `b` inplace and doesn't create a new list. And `b` is the list being kept in the tuple of default values. So all your changes to the list are saved there, and each invocation of the function works with the different value of `b`.